# Sample X509 Certificates with Wrong ASN.1 Encode

Tags: x509certificate, asn.1

For testing purpose, I am looking for sample X509 Certificates with wrong ASN.1 encoding, like Null with length more then Zero, etc. Any pointers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any certificate and save it to file.

Download [Asn.1 editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor) and open the certificate in it. Now doubleclik any asn.1 element and edit it (i.e. change value of an oid. it will at least invalidate the signature). If you want to break asn.1 encoding then then view it in hex to find what byte to edit.

When you select NULL asn.1 element it will show you in hex viewer what bytes it is encoded in. Green color represents Length octet. Change it in any hex editor.